# Grunt job (imagemin) failed due to Write EPIPE error

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-imagemin

When i run a grunt job, the build is failed due to the below error

```
+ grunt imagemin --stack
[4mRunning "imagemin:dist" (imagemin) task[24m
[31mFatal error: write EPIPE[39m

Error: write EPIPE
    at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:856:11)
    at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:879:20)
    at WriteWrap.afterWrite (net.js:763:14)
```

the versions used are : 
**node-version-v5.5.0,
grunt-cli v1.2.0,
grunt v0.4.5,
bower -version -1.7.7**

Trials:
1. deleted grunt-contrib-imagemin folder from nodemodules and re-installed using npm install - this didnot work 
2. exit-on-epipe - solution mentioned [here](https://github.com/SheetJS/node-exit-on-epipe/blob/master/README.md) - this too didnot work
3. restarting the server after installation is also done but of no use.

Thanks in advance